# Problemas ao listar dados de tabelas relacionadas no Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou trabalhando com php, laravel 5.3 e myql.
Após ter criado tudo (Migration, model,controller, View, relacionamento),  está me dando o seguinte erro:

> ErrorException in 1d01653e0e29121ce444ef5c2072fb4d52e5e7db.php line 12:
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Projecto5_3\resources\views\produtos\index.blade.php)

Mas, quando removo da view a linha

```
 <p style="color: #069">{{ $produto->categs->nome_cat }}</p>
```

aparecem somente os dados da tabela produto. Como resolver esse problema?

Código.

**Migration categs**

```
class CreateCategsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('nome_cat');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categs');
    }
}
```

**Migration produtos**

```
class CreateProdutosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('produtos', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('nome');
            $table->text('descricao');
            $table->unsignedinteger('categs_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('categs_id')->references('id')->on('categs');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('produtos');
    }
}
```

**Model categs**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class categ extends Model
{
    //Relacionamento 1:n Categoria dos produtos

    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\produtos');
    }
}
```

**Model produtos**

```html
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produtos extends Model
{
    //
    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\categs');
    }
}
```

**Controller produtos**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Produtos;

class ProdutosController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $produtos = Produtos::all();
        return view('produtos.index',['todosprodutos'=>$produtos]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('produtos.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nome' => 'required',
            'descricao' => 'required'
            ]);

        $produtos = new Produtos;
        $produtos->nome = $request->nome;
        $produtos->descricao = $request->descricao;
        $produtos->id_cat = $request->id_cat;
        $produtos->save();

        return redirect('produtos')->with('message', 'Produto gravado com sucesso!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $produtos = Produtos::find($id);
        if(!$produtos)
            {abort(404);}
        return view('produtos.details')->with('detailpage',$produtos);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $produtos = Produtos::find($id);
        if(!$produtos)
            {abort(404);}
        return view('produtos.edit')->with('detailpage',$produtos);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nome' => 'required',
            'descricao' => 'required',
        ]);

        $produtos = Produtos::find($id);
        $produtos->nome = $request->nome;
        $produtos->descricao = $request->descricao;
        $produtos->save();
        return redirect('produtos')->with('message', 'Produto actualizado com sucesso!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $produtos = Produtos::find($id);
        $produtos->delete();
        return redirect('produtos')->with('message', 'Produto excluido com sucesso!');
    }
}
```

**View produto - index**

```
@extends('novomaster')
{{ Session::get('message') }}
@section('left-sidebar')
<h1 style=" color: #069">Produtos</h1>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="produtos/create">Novo Produto</a>
<hr>

    @foreach($todosprodutos as $produto)
    <div class="alert alert-info" style="background-color:#C9DCFC">
        <h2><a href="/produtos/{{ $produto->id }}">{{ $produto->nome }}</a></h2>      
        <p style="color: #FFF">{{  $produto->descricao  }}</p>
        <p style="color: #069">{{ $produto->categs->nome_cat }}</p>
        <br />  


        <form action="/produtos/{{ $produto->id }}" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" href="/produtos/{{ $produto->id }}/edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>

            <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger" type="submit" name="name" value="Apagar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>

       </form>
    </div> 
   @endforeach
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `model`, como não foi padrão o nome da chave, então, tem que configurar seu `model` para receber essa chave na configuração:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class categ extends Model
{
    //Relacionamento 1:n Categoria dos produtos

    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Produtos', 'categs_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produtos extends Model
{
    //
    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\categ','categs_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

agora com as configurações da chave e a relação, vai funcionar a carga de dados para essas relações. ***Outro ponto é a observar:*** porque `categ` se a primeira letra deveria ser maiúscula, ou seja, `Categ`, e o outro `model` está correto `Produtos`? a falta de padrão causa isso confusões no código, então siga a nomenclatura correta todos os `models` começando com a primeira letra em maiúsculo, exemplo `Categoria`, `Produto`, `Cliente`, etc e não corte o nome também em vez de `Categ` coloque `Categoria`, ao meu ver isso facilita muito o desenvolvimento e a manutenção!, mas, eu fiz diante do que está na sua pergunta, são recomendações.

---

No método do `controller` mude, como exemplo abaixo:

```
public function index()
{
    $produtos = Produtos::with('categoria')->get();
    return view('produtos.index',['todosprodutos'=>$produtos]);
}
```

sendo que o `with` carregará a relação, e na sua `View` mude:

```
<p style="color: #069">{{ $produto->categoria->nome_cat }}</p>
```

***Observação:*** o nome que está na relação do seu `model` é o mesmo nome do método que você tentava acessar.!

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)
- [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
- [Defining Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: Obrigado @Virgilio, fiz do jeito que me sugeriu, sumiu aquele erro e surgiu outro: FatalErrorException in Model.php line 779:
Class 'App\categs' not found. Pelo que notei, não está achando a class nesta linha do model produto: return $this->belongsTo('App\categs'); O quê faço?

Comment: Percebi que nesta linha "return $this->belongsTo('App\categs');" o nome do model é 'App\categ' e não 'App\categs', ainda assim continuou erro. Na view, alterei de: <p style="color: #069">{{ $produto->categoria->nome_cat }}</p>, para <p style="color: #069">{{ $produto->categoria['nome_cat'] }}</p>, não está trazendo a categoria do produto, traz apenas os dados da tabela produto.

Comment: Tentei o seguinte no tinker: $prod=App\Produtos::find(2), me retornou o produto desejado. Para saber a sua categ, fiz assim: $prod->categ, me retornou NULL. Afinal de contas, o que se passa? O que tenho de fazer? Por favor ajudem-me.

Comment: @DanieldosSantos seu código olhando bem tem problemas. Eu já vi  o que é vou postar daqui a pouco aguarde já te aviso

Comment: @DanieldosSantos eu fiz a edição, não carregava devido a falta de configuração da chave de relacionamento, como você não colocou padrão, deve ser informado nos parâmetros de  `belongsTo` e `hasMany`, e a segunda parte continue com o carregamento `Produtos::with('categoria')->get();` ele é otimizado utilize ele e verifique se os dados foram retornados. E cara tome cuidado com padrão, leia a documentação do Laravel ela é bem rica e tem todo os detalhes das configurações vide minha resposta parte `Referencias`

Comment: com base no disseste acima fiz o seguinte: No model Produtos,  return $this->belongsTo('App\categ','foreignKey'); e no model categ, return $this->hasMany('App\produtos','foreignKey'); Mesmo assim não está a resultar.

Comment: Olha cara é assim que é pra funcionar voce deve esta fazendo algo de errado, porque isso consta na documentação .... Verifique todo seu código @DanieldosSantos

Comment: Outro ponto nao é foreingKey no nome da relação é o nome que corresponde passando as 3 posições igual eu coloquei na resposta @DanieldosSantos

Comment: Funcionou!!!!! Muito obrigado @VirgilioNovic pela ajuda e pelas recomendações que me deixou. Muito obrigado, que Deus lhe abençoe.

Comment: A questão anterior já está solucionada. Agora, está me dando erro ao salvar os dados do produto, propriamente a chave estrangeira categs_id no banco de dados. Está dando o seguinte erro: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'categs_id' cannot be null .

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63048/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-daniel-dos-santos).

Comment: @DanieldosSantos se pode abrir outro questionamento esse já foi sanado, cada questionamento gera um pergunta e nenhuma ou uma ou varias respostas .. tudo bem? abra, coloque o controller, coloque o que você está fazendo e como chegou nesse erro